# Looking for list of d3.js equivalents of jQuery operators

Tags: jquery, d3.js

Does anyone know of a comprehensive list of d3.js equivalents (or near-equivalents) of jQuery operators/methods?

(It kinda sucks to load jQuery for not other purpose other than being able to make one call to, e.g. `$('#frobozz').height()`, when I already have `d3.js` around.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, there isn't such a list because `d3` doesn't by design provide any such functions. However, now that most browsers are *starting* to conform to the [W3C standard](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/), you do not need `jQuery` for *some* functions.

You can get access to the `DOMElement` by calling [selection.node()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-node) and then you can use the DOM API available on the element or you can use [`selection.style`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-style) to get `CSS` properties directly.

There, however, still are parts of the API which are not adhered to by some browsers, or tricky to implement, and `jQuery` is going to be the best way of making Javascript programs browser agnostic and simple. The `jQuery.height` function, for example, [is not trivial](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L108).

The only cases when you do not need `jQuery` is in simple cases. Say, you know that the `height` is explicitly set via CSS, then it can be obtained as `d3.select('#froboxx').node().style.height`, or `d3.select('#froboxx').style('height')`. Or if it is an element where `height` is set as an attribute (e.g. `svg` or `img` element), then `d3.select('#froboxx').attr('height')` will also calculate the value for you. However, when *both* are set, then the [precedence of style v/s attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/cascade.html#q12) kicks in and the task again becomes non-trivial.

One compromise possible since jQuery 1.8 is that you can prepare [your own `jQuery` build](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#modules-new-in-18) which does not include any modules you do not need. The downside is that you'll have to host the file on your servers. Another alternate along those lines is using [`ZeptoJS`](http://zeptojs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There's certainly no comprehensive list of this. Selectors however are quite similar to jQuery with `$` replaced with `d3.select` or `d3.selectAll`. Operators such as `.height()` would be equivalent to `.attr("height")`.

For any particular case it should be easy enough to figure out what to call with D3 so that you don't have to load jQuery. After all, you're accessing DOM elements in either case.